# Ubuntu issues with $BASH_VERSION and new user

Tags: bash, user, version

I'm logging into my new Ubuntu VPS via SSH from a terminal in Ubuntu desktop. I have created a new user *adam*, which I've added to the sudo group, so I don't have to log in as root all the time. When I login as root everything is as expected, except when I login in as adam I'm having some issues with the `$BASH_VERSION` environment var.

I've not changed anything within the default `.profile` and `.bashrc` files, so I should have all the default settings. I noticed though in `.profile` there is a condition around including `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
```

Except when I echo `$BASH_VERSION` from the CL I get nothing back, just an empty line. Something seems really screwed here but it's just a little beyond my knowledge.

Incase it's useful, here's what I used to create the user:

```
useradd -d /home/adam -m adam
sudo passwd adam
usermod -a -G sudo adam
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default shell equivalent of `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu is `/bin/dash`, not `/bin/bash`. Check your shell.

Comment: Awesome! I don't quite understand why it wasn't set to the correct value to start with, but you set me on the right track. Although `/bin/dash` didn't work, `/bin/bash` did.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. To fix it do:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash adam
```

Comment: Hi Balthasar. Welcome to the Stack Exchange network! The first part of your answer is correct but you were probably downvoted because the second part is unclear / incorrect;  `useradd -D` (by itselft) simply prints the default `useradd` configuration. It would be best to edit your answer to improve it.